# Как проверить права доступа к директории?

Tags: c#

Нужно при переборе папок/файлов из корня диска проверять доступ на чтение и после этого с доступными файлами проводить операции чтения, копирования и т.п.. Как проверить наличие прав доступа на чтение текущей директории в таком случае:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");   
foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dir.GetDirectories())
{
    //TODO: проверка di на доступ
    //TODO: обработка di
}
```

?

Comment: Ваш подход неверен. Информация о правах на доступ к директории не имеет смысла, потому что после вашей проверки в следующее мгновение эти права могут поменяться. Вы не имеете права рассчитывать на проверку перед операцией.

Просто проводите операцию без проверки, и ловите исключения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rules = di.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
{
    if ((FileSystemRights.Read & rule.FileSystemRights) == 1)
    //то, что нужно сделать
}
```